# I need to let users create profile pages on the fly

Tags: php, web-applications, dynamic, file-upload, social-networking

I'm creating a slight rip off of Facebook for an internal web-app at my company.

How do I let users create a page, and then have my script create a new file and save it the server?

My plan is to use the typical file functions. But I was wondering if I should just do the entire thing with query strings, and give people ID's.

Thoughts?

Comment: Since it's an internal site, what would be wrong with SharePoint?

Comment: If you are storing the profile information in just a file you might want to rethink you design and use a database.

Comment: As @Danny said, you should really use a database for this (whether using an RDBMS or a NoSQL DBMS). If you are not familiar with them, you should get familiar with them. It will be worth the effort, trust me.

Comment: like the other comments say, you'd be far better off installing an open source CMS (drupal, joomla, etc.) and using that-- it'd be way more featureful, secure, and probably better looking too.

Comment: @Danny - thanks I was thinking I'd just use a database and dynamically create pages.

Comment: @Julio I'd love to use a CMS, but theres something with the project that prevents that :(. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider installing a proper social networking package, like Elgg.